# C# request a webpage failed but successd using web browser (Well checked the header and cookies)

Tags: c#, webrequest

My friend is using C# to write a simple program for requesting a webpage.
However he encounter a problem when try to request a specified webpage.
He have already tried to set all the header and cookie inside the request, but it still got the timeout exception.
The example webpage is https://my.ooma.com

Here is the code:

```
string url = "https://my.ooma.com";
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
request.Timeout = 30000;
request.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/536.5 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/19.0.1084.52 Safari/536.5";
request.Method = "GET";
request.CookieContainer = new CookieContainer();
request.Accept = "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8";
request.Headers.Add("Accept-Charset:ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.3");
request.Headers.Add("Accept-Encoding:gzip,deflate,sdch");
request.Headers.Add("Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8");
request.KeepAlive = true;                 

WebResponse myResponse = request.GetResponse();
StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(myResponse.GetResponseStream());
string result = sr.ReadToEnd();
sr.Close();
myResponse.Close();
```

All the headers is as same as when using Chrome to browse the webpage.
And he didn't see any cookies set by using the Chrome developer tool.
Do anyone can success request the page using C#?
Thanks a lot.

Comment: What is the problem he encountered?

Comment: he cannot get the source content of that webpage. The program keep got a timeout operation exception.

Comment: Maybe that webpage has to add some specified headers/cookies, but I cannot any of these.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry for being late.
The following code snippet should work just fine. I also tried with tour old URL that had "getodds.xgi" in it and it also worked fine.
The server uses a secure sockets layer (SSL) protocol for connections that use the Secure Hypertext Transfer Protocol (HTTPS) scheme only.

You don't need to set any UserAgent or Header if they were just intended to get response.

```
ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Ssl3;
WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create("http://my.ooma.com/");
string htmlResponse = string.Empty;
using (WebResponse response = request.GetResponse())
{
     using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
     {
         htmlResponse = reader.ReadToEnd();
         reader.Close();
     }
     response.Close();
}
```